# When using Bootstrap webjars, is it possible to override properties globally without having to recompile the sass?

Tags: bootstrap-5, webjars

I'm researching replacing dojo 1.16 and a custom ITCSS model with bootstrap 5.3. I'm currently using the bootstrap 5.3.2 webjars, but I want to be able to customize things like the breadcrumb style and the colors without having to recompile the entire CSS file during the build stage, and preferably while still being able to use Bootstrap named variables like colors and the like. is this possible? All I can find on the bootstrap documentation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/ either involves recompiling the SCSS files or having to redefine CSS variables that I think don't support named variables.